# C++ Copy None Existing Elements from one Vector to another

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I have a class like this:

```
struct DataElement {
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    std::string placeholder;
    // some other data members
}
```

I store them inside a Vector.
Now i have a function which takes a `vector` of these `DataElement` and also creates a `vector` of the `DataElement`.

```
std::vector<DataElement> doAction(std::vector<DataElement>& data) {
    auto additional_data = create_additional_data() //returns std::vector<DataElement>
    //merge data and additional_data
    return additional_data
}
```

Now i want to copy all the Elements from the `vector data` into the `vector additional_data` if there key is not already there.

I was thinking of using `copy_if` but how do i check if the current element is already in the Destination?

Comment: You can use `std::find` on the `additional_data` captured in the lambda. However, this is o(N²). If this is critical, you can maintain a cache of the "already copied values".

Comment: Actually: Depends on the context and the datasize. And system requirements. It might even be faster to build up a map and then finally convert that back to a vector.

Comment: Better to use a map or set to copy unique items. Searching a vector would be `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to check if the current element is already in the Destination with an additional `unordered_map`

```cpp
std::vector<DataElement> doAction(std::vector<DataElement>& data) {
    std::vector<DataElement> result = data;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, DataElement> merged;
    for(const auto& e: data){
     merged[e.key] = e;
    }

    auto additional_data = create_additional_data() //returns std::vector<DataElement>
    // Time complexity: O(N)
    for(const auto &e: additional_data){
    // it's O(1) complexity
    if(merged.find(e.key) == merged.end()){
        result.push_back(e);
        merged[e.key] = e;
       }
    }
    //merge data and additional_data
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::find_if` to check if an element with given key is already in the vector.

However, `std::find_if` is `O(N)` and when you do it for `N` elements you end up with a `O(N^2)`. Consider to use `std::unordered_map` instead of vectors. `std::unordered_map::insert` is `O(1)` on average for inserting a single element.

If you cannot switch to `std::unordered_map`, you can still use one while building the vector:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

struct DataElement {
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    std::string placeholder;
    // some other data members
};

std::vector<DataElement> create_additional_data() { return {}; }

std::vector<DataElement> doAction(std::vector<DataElement>& data) {
    auto additional_data = create_additional_data();

    std::vector<DataElement> result;
    std::unordered_map<std::string,DataElement> temp;

    
    for (const auto& e : data) { temp.insert({e.key,e}); }
    //merge data and additional_data

    // element is not inserted when key is already present !
    for (const auto& e : additional_data) { temp.insert({e.key,e});} 

    for (const auto& e : temp) { result.push_back(e.second); }

    return result;
}
```

I wasnt sure from which vector you want to keep the element when both vectors contain one for a given key. The above code uses the one from `data` and the one from `additional_data` is only inserted when it wasnt present in `data`. Its just a matter of switching order of the two loops.